# Is there a simple way to add a legend explaining vertex colors to a fruchterman reingold plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have a fruchterman reingold plot of 20 random students' extra curricular activities with the vertex color based on their final grades (numeric, ranging from 0-20) in an associated data set. Is there a way to to display a legend that prints the range for each vertex color?

```
library(igraph)

a <- graph.adjacency(sport,mode="undirected")

plot(a,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.size=6, vertex.color=portsmall$G3)
```

Here is a impage of my plot with colored vertices:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vc3j.png

Comment: `graph.adjacency` is not a function in base R. Could you add the names of the packages you are using as well as a reproducible example?

Comment: the package is igraph, what do you need for a reproducible example (so I can make sure to provide everything)?

Comment: There is a post about [minimum, complete, and verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as a post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `legend` function. For example:

```
legend("top",legend=c(1,2,3),fill=c("red","green","blue"))
```

You'll need to work out the precise nature of the parameters since we don't have your data so we can't guess. Read the docs for `legend` for more.